# Perl + Word: Degree sign shows up preceded by A-circumflex

Tags: perl, ms-word, ole

I'm generating a Word document in Perl, and I'd like to include the degree symbol (°) in the text I generate.  If I generate the code like so:

`$cell .= qq/\xB0/;`

This works, and generates (for a value of `$cell` of `55`): 55°

However, perlcritic complains at me when I do this and suggests I use this construction instead:

`$cell .= qq/\N{DEGREE SIGN}/;`

This does not work; it generates: 55Â°

Looking through my code in `perl -d`, I see that running the following code:

```
my $cell = 55;
$cell .= qq/\N{DEGREE SIGN}/; # the PBP way
print sprintf("%x\n", ord($_)) for split //, $cell;
```

```
my $cell = 55;
$cell .= qq/\xB0/; # the non-PBP way
print sprintf("%x\n", ord($_)) for split //, $cell;
```

results in:

```
35
35
b0
```

I'm outputting text to the Word document using [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-OLE-0.1709/lib/Win32/OLE.pm):

```
my @column_headings = @{ shift $args->{'data'} };
my @rows            = @{ $args->{'data'} };

my $word   = Win32::OLE->new( 'Word.Application', 'Quit' );
my $doc    = $word->Documents->Add();
my $select = $word->Selection;

$csv->combine(@column_headings);
$select->InsertAfter( $csv->string );
$select->InsertParagraphAfter;
for my $row (@rows) {
    $csv->combine( @{$row} );
    $select->InsertAfter( $csv->string );
    $select->InsertParagraphAfter;
}
my $table = 
  $select->ConvertToTable( { 'Separator' => wdSeparateByCommas } );
$table->Rows->First->Range->Font->{'Bold'} = 1;
$table->Rows->First->Range->ParagraphFormat->{'Alignment'} =
  wdAlignParagraphCenter;
@{ $table->Rows->First->Borders(wdBorderBottom) }{qw/LineStyle LineWidth/}
  = ( wdLineStyleDouble, wdLineWidth100pt );
$doc->SaveAs( { 'Filename' => Cwd::getcwd . '/test.doc' } );
```

What can I do to get rid of the extraneous Â?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. I'm still trying to figure out encoding myself but you might try setting your output file to UTF-8. This article might help too: http://forums.devshed.com/perl-programming-6/replace-degree-symbol-421097.html

Comment: @scrappedcola It probably is some kind of encoding issue - originally, I was using the ASCII degree sign, but I found that Word didn't interpret that as such.

Comment: See @ikegami's comment to the answer for the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you are suffering from encoding issues. The degree sign is `U+00B0`, but this serializes to UTF-8 `C2 B0`, which renders as `°` — if this multi byte character is correctly decoded as utf-8. If you were decoding the bytes as a single-byte encoding (say … cp1252), then the bytes would be considered seperate, and would display `Â °`.

Now clearly, the solution is either to tell Perl to transform the unicode string to a byte string of cp1252 chars (the horror!). You will find the `my $bytestring = Encode::encode("cp1252", $string)` function interesting here.

Or you tell the document that it will consider itself UTF-8. I don't know how you would do that, but there *has* to be an option *somewhere*. This would actually be preferable, as there are thousands of characters that (unlike the °) don't fit into cp1252. Like the degree Celsius ℃ (U+2103) or degree Fahrenheit ℉ (U+2109) characters ;-)

Comment: Re your last paragraph, you'd have to use the "W"IDE interface to talk to Word instead of the "A"NSI interface. That's a decision out of your hands.

Comment: Actually, I think you can do `Win32::OLE->Option(CP => Win32::OLE::CP_UTF8)`! Then you'd use `my $bytestring = Encode::encode("UTF-8", $string);`. Untested. I hope it works!

Comment: @ikegami Setting the codepage took care of it, and there was no need to call Encode::encode(). You are full of helpfulness.

Comment: No, you do need to call `encode` or it won't work for some strings. In fact, not calling `encode` should give you a "Wide character" error. (It's a bug in Win32::OLE that it doesn't.)